# Invalid certificate but expires in 1 year?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I've refreshed my SSL certificates and I'm hosting a FastAPI. However, I get a
[image]

Although when I look at the certificate it's still valid?

[image]

Has anyone had this before?

Best,
Confused Man

Comment: It does not say in what you show that the certificate is invalid because it is expired.  Please provide the exact error message you get from the browser instead, i.e. something like NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID or similar. And if it really says expired then check the time on your system to make sure it is the current one.

Comment: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

is there error...

Comment: This error means that the issuer of the certificate is not trusted - which is very different from the certificate being expired. So probably you've configured your server wrong. Check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).